# How to run Hashicorp Vault as a service on CentOS in production

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm running the latest CentOS and I need Hashicorp Vault 1.6.3 to run as a service. I'm currently using the kv/secret background, so I can use

```
Vault kv put secret/test/hello foo=bar
```

In order to store secrets. When running vault as a server, it blocks. I need the Vault server to automatically start as a service whenever the server is rebooted, it really shouldn't be blocking if possible. It's been about three years since I've used Vault so I may just be dense here.

So I guess what I need to ask is:

1. How do I start Vault when my server reboots.
2. Should it be blocking and, if no, how do I prevent this?

Comment: You may want to ask this on ServerFault instead.

Comment: I posted to serverfault just now, hoping someone either here or there can get an answer to this.